# Wrap a C API function returning pointer into macro call

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I am trying to wrap C API functions returning `int` in some cases and pointers in other into macro that would check condition and provide diagnostics and throw exception in case of error. For functions returning `int` it is simple as I do not need that `int`:

```
#define CALL_INT( name, ... ) do { \
        if( !name( __VA_ARGS__ ) ) throw std::runtime_error( #name " failed" );
     } while(0)

  // using it
  CALL_INT( foo, arg );
```

but for functions returning pointer it is not that simple, as I need to check that pointer against `nullptr` and then assign it to my pointer. So is it possible to write similar macro, so this expression would work:

```
auto ptr = CALL_PTR( foobar, arg1, arg2 );
```

ie it would produce code, that calls `foobar( arg1, arg2 )` check result against `nullptr` and make it available for assignment if no error happened.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way instead of making a template wrapper?

Comment: @krzaq Template wrapper cannot stringify function name

Comment: Would a solution that uses macro only to pass function name to a templated wrapper be satisfactory to you?

Comment: @krzaq yes sure, anyway you should provide that answer as it could be usable for somebody else

Comment: Why not `VERIFY( bob = name( a , b , c ) )`?

Answer (score 3):

The real solution is: don't use macros. Just write the you want to do inline. You, and everybody else, will thank yourself later.

---

The literal solution would be to just immediately invoke a lambda:

```
#define MAYBE_THROW(f, ...)                                   \
    [&]{                                                      \
        auto _result = f(__VA_ARGS__);                        \
        if (!_result) throw std::runtime_error(#f " failed"); \
        return _result;                                       \
    }()

MAYBE_THROW(foo, arg);
auto ptr = MAYBE_THROW(foobar, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Problem with inline functions - with every call I will have to copy paste code again and again with all issues that this leads to.

Comment: Works! Just lead semicolon needs to be removed. Why do you capture in this lambda?

Comment: @Slava to pass parameters to the api function they need to be captured

Comment: @krzaq it compiles fine for me without capture, hmm maybe I do something wrong

Comment: @slava are you passing literals to the macro? They don't need to be captured, but variables woulld have to be

Comment: @krzaq yes, I did not pass local vars yet, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Less magic is better

```
#define VERIFY( ... ) \
  [&](){
     auto r = __VA_ARGS__;
     if (!r) throw std::runtime_error( #__VA_ARGS__ " failed" );
     return r;
  }()
```

This takes an expression.  It runs it.  It then tests it and throws if it fails.

If it fails, it includes the entire expression in the throw.

It then returns it.

There is less magic, in that `VERIFY(bob)` is just doing `bob`.  You can do

```
int x = VERIFY( call(a,b,c) );
```

or

```
VERIFY( y = call(a,b,c) );
```

or whatever.  The primary code run is there; only the assert wrappers are missing for when it fails.

`VERIFY` is also known as a macro that does this generally.